# Algorithm that Recognize Images in a Document and Automatically Remove it

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have the image below:

[image]

What algorithm can I use to recognize an image from an image text document ? I want to remove images from the document to decrease text extraction error rate. I want to segment image. I dont know what possible approach I can use to deal with it. Any idea?

Comment: One approach in order is: convert image to grayscale, gaussian blur, threshold, Canny edge detection, find contours, iterate through contours and filter with a minimum threshold area. All contours greater than a minimum threshold area must be images. Create a mask and draw all contours that fit this filter. At this point we have all images in "white", we invert the mask with bitwise-not then bitwise-and this inverted image with the original photo to remove all images from the document. The result should be the document with only words

Comment: @nathancy - what if the images is as small as the text region. Will it still work?

Comment: I think it should work since the contour of each individual contour letter is much smaller. By using a defined minimum threshold value it should only detect the images. You may run into problems if the image size is as small as a single letter but should be fine if its the size of the text region

Answer (score 1):

You follow the below: *(descriptions are in the code comments)*

```
namedWindow("Original_Image", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
namedWindow("Result", cv::WINDOW_FREERATIO);
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("5ZKfM.png");
cv::Mat copy;   // this just for showing image
img.copyTo(copy);

// to gray
cv::Mat gray;
cvtColor(img, gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
cv::Mat binaryImg;
// threshold the img to get a binary image
threshold(gray, binaryImg, 80, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

cv::morphologyEx(binaryImg, binaryImg, cv::MORPH_CLOSE, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5)));

// Floodfill from point (0, 0)
cv::Mat im_floodfill = binaryImg.clone();
cv::floodFill(im_floodfill, cv::Point(0, 0), cv::Scalar(255));

// Invert floodfilled image
cv::Mat im_floodfill_inv;
bitwise_not(im_floodfill, im_floodfill_inv);
// Combine the two images to get the foreground.
cv::bitwise_or(im_floodfill_inv, binaryImg, binaryImg);

// find the contours
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(binaryImg, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

// get the largest contoure
cv::Rect rect;
for (std::vector<cv::Point> &contour : contours) {
    cv::Rect tempRect = cv::boundingRect(contour);
    if(tempRect.area() > rect.area()) {
        rect = tempRect;
    }
}

// get the sub mat of the picture from the original image
cv::Mat submatOriginal = img(rect);
// prepare the mask
cv::Mat submatBinary = binaryImg(rect);
// remove the picture from the image (set all pixels to white)
submatOriginal.setTo(cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), submatBinary);

imshow("Result", img);
imshow("Original_Image", copy);
cv::waitKey();
```

**And this is the result:**

[image]

Note: Code is C++, but you can follow the steps, and reimplement it in Python.

Comment: Thank you so much, what if the images is as small as the text region. Will it still work?

Comment: I think it will work because the density of the image is bigger than the text, and also you should play with parameters as well, and fine-tune the best parameters as your need.